# Oracle primary key affecting indexes

Tags: database, performance, oracle, indexing

I had an index working really nicely last night, low I/O all that good stuff. Now this morning I added a primary key to the table and the performance has dropped and the optimizer ignores the index even with hints.. Any advice? Thankyou

Schema structure..

```
      Product
      ID       PK
      Name     
      Price   

      Order_Line
      Order_ID    FK
      Product_ID  FK
      Qty

      Orders
      ID             PK
      O_Date date
      CustID
```

Query...

```
      SELECT SUM(OL.QTY) FROM  PRODUCT P,ORDERS O, ORDER_LINE OL   
      WHERE
      P.NAME = 'APRICOT JAM'
      AND
      P.ID = OL.PRODUCT_ID
      AND
      O.O_DATE = '03-MAR-2014'
      AND
      OL.ORDER_ID= O.ID
      ;
```

The index which it isn't using is a composite index on product which is (name,ID), instead its using products primary key to do an index range scan Thanks!

Comment: Please post the structure of the table, index and primary key. Also the query you are running against the table.

Comment: Hi ok will do that now! Thanks! :)

Comment: Product table shows only a PK on ID - which actually looks OK. I wouldn't understand why you would have a composite key on ID / Name.

Comment: With the index the total number of gets is about 2000 but when I included the primary key this went up to 195000 gets. Would this be something to do with statistics? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the before-and-after execution plans. It looks like it's maybe changed the join order. You haven't said what the index being ignored is - on `product.name`? I'd guess it was using `product` as the driving table, now it's switched to use `orders`? (Also, are your FKs indexed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Table
ID       PK
Name     INDEX01
Price

I would structure your table this way.
Your query is going to range scan because it is going to scan the table for the P.NAME = 'APRICOT JAM' clause in your query.